# Converting VB 2008 to VB 2012: Need Windows CE support

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012, windows-ce

I've recently inherited a legacy project that was originally written in VB 2008. I was given a VB 2012 Pro environment to work in. The final product lives on a series of Windows CE mobile devices. I have some experience in VB 2005/08, but none in 2012.

When I open the project in VB 2012. I get the following error. Unfortunatly the link is bad.

- The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12395&pver=11&sbp=ProjectTypeDeprecated&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=MSDN&sar=ProjectCompatibility&o1=68B1623D-7FB9-47D8-8664-7ECEA3297D4F

So far I have found conflicting articles that say VB 2012 was GOING TO support Windows CE and smart devices, but other articles that say it doesn't.

Question:

1. Does VB 2012 support Windows CE and smart devices?
2. If not inherently supported, can anyone think of a workaround or another direction to take my research?

Comment: VS 2008 is the last version to support these platforms.  You will need that environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, you cannot build for Windows CE devices with Studio 2012.  It will support WEC2013 (effectively CE 8) soon, but will never support any older version of CE.
2. The "workaround" is to install and use Studio 2008.  Seriously.  I do CE development nearly every day, and I still have Studio 2008 installed on every PC for that reason.  It's a real pain, but it's the only option.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was afraid that was going to be the answer based on everything I've read so far.

Comment: If you purchased VS2010, you got VS2008 for free. And what about VS2012?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can not use VS2012 for WindowsCE.

VS2008 is the last version to support WindowsCE platform/application development.